# is it optimal to create class instance of iterable using __iter__ and __next__ compared using a list instance attribute?

Tags: python, benchmarking, iterable

Intuitively, using `__iter__` and `__next__` seems likely to be significantly for efficient, but I curious of the technical specifics of why, and how one maybe go about benchmarking to measure and compare the space and runtime of these?

A common case I can think of is a Linked List,

The following is an implementation illustration the use of `__iter__` and `__next__`:

I have tried various benchmarking tools without much success being able to generate data to more closely analyze they're internals; specifically, how exactly the magic methods function, and if they're truly as significantly more efficient as I surmise they are.

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value: int, next_node):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next_node

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = None
        self._current = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} {}>'.format(type(self).__name__, self.head)

    def __iter__(self):
        self._current = self.head
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._current is None:
            raise StopIteration
        current, self._current = self._current, self._current.next
        return current

    @property
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def prepend_node(self, valuetoadd: int):
        self.head = IntNode(valuetoadd, self.head)
```

Compared to the following:

```py
class ListNode:
    """
    A node in a singly-linked list.
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
​
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)
​
​
class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Create a new singly-linked list.
        Takes O(1) time.
        """
        self.head = None
​
​
    def prepend(self, data):
        """
        Insert a new element at the beginning of the list.
        Takes O(1) time.
        """
        self.head = ListNode(data=data, next=self.head)

def find(self, key):
        """
        Search for the first element with `data` matching
        `key`. Return the element or `None` if not found.
        Takes O(n) time.
        """
        curr = self.head
        while curr and curr.data != key:
            curr = curr.next
        return curr  # Will be None if not found

    def remove(self, key):
        """
        Remove the first occurrence of `key` in the list.
        Takes O(n) time.
        """
        # Find the element and keep a
        # reference to the element preceding it
        curr = self.head
        prev = None
        while curr and curr.data != key:
            prev = curr
            curr = curr.next
        # Unlink it from the list
        if prev is None:
            self.head = curr.next
        elif curr:
            prev.next = curr.next
            curr.next = None
```

Comment: For you to benchmark the two approaches, you'd need to have two pieces of code that do the same thing using the different approaches.  I'm not seeing that here.  But I agree with Carc above; in theory I don't think there's any performance difference, but if you had a couple of examples of iterating via iterator vs twiddling the attributes directly, I think it'd be apparent that the iterator approach makes for code that's much more concise and easy to maintain.

Comment: Don't make a container its own iterator! A container's `__iter__` should return a new object, usually handled by writing it as a generator function.